# What's the most seamless way to work over ssh on OSX?

Tags: ssh, scp, web-development

There's something just wrong about scp'ing every file you've changed. I normally use Sublime Text 2 - is there an editor or something that can upload files right as they are changed via scp?

If not, is there an efficient way to go about developing remotely?

Comment: I use Dropbox to sync files on a remote development machine.  Not sure if this is the kind of answer you are looking for though.

Comment: Thanks for your input michael. Everything has to be encrypted however, and frankly I don't really trust dropbox to keep my stuff safe

Comment: You can use an encrypted disk image in OS X.  The name escapes me at the moment, but you can make it sparse, so takes up less room.

Comment: Another option I've just found is https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/ - a daemon that automatically rsyncs a directory when files are changed (using inotify or fsevents), so that's kind of like using Dropbox without Dropbox in the middle, but I know nothing more about it.

Comment: vim (local instance) can edit over ssh

Comment: @therefromhere, it seems to be what I need but is missing lua: configure: error: Need a Lua toolchain with matching versions ('lua' library and 'lua' and 'luac' programs)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958056/how-to-use-sublime-over-ssh

Answer (score 0):

With SSHFS you can mount a remove filesystem via SSH, that's about as seamless as you can get, but you'll need a very low latency connection for it to be useable.

e.g. it's fine for working on a dev server that's in the next room.

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

Comment: This looks interesting, but my ping is about ~50-100ms. Why is that relevant for a one-way save?

Comment: Because your editor might hang while it waits for the save to finish, also searching might be painful.  Give it a go though.